Can two formulas be “valid under the same interpretations”?
Ebbinghaus 2021:

A formula φ is valid (written “⊨ φ”) iff ∅ ⊨ φ.
Thus, a formula is valid if and only if it holds under all interpretations.

Let’s break this down:
First of all, it is stated in the text that the double-turnstile symbol ‘⊨’ will be used to denote both the satisfaction relation and the consequence relation.
The satisfaction relation is between a formula/set of formulas, and an interpretation.
The consequence relation is between a formula, and a formula/set of formulas.
By saying ‘∅ ⊨ φ’, the author is saying, “φ is a consequence of an empty set of formulas”.
A consequence is when a formula has the exact same models as some other formulas. In other words, they cannot exist apart from each other.
The empty set is a subset of every set (except itself). Perhaps counterintuitively, all structures imaginable count as models of an empty set of formulas, since they technically fulfill all the formulas in the set, since there aren’t any.
Thus, a formula is valid if it is satisfied by every possible structure. (In other words, it is a tautology).
On the next page, the author says:

The formulas φ and ψ are said to be logically equivalent (written “φ=||=ψ”) iff φ|=ψ and ψ|=φ.
Thus the formulas φ and ψ are logically equivalent iff they are valid under the same interpretations, that is, iff |= φ ↔ ψ.

The last part I find confusing.
The definition of “valid” just given was that it is satisfied in all possible interpretations. That definition did not explain what “valid under an interpretation” would mean.
I can assume that the author just means “are satisfied under the same interpretations”. But to be fair, they don’t spell out a proof for how that can be used to conclude “|= φ ↔ ψ”, which says “formula φ ↔ ψ is valid”.
It makes sense to me intuitively, but I’d like to spell out a proof.

Two formulas are logically equivalent iff they have the same truth value in every interpretation that means that the corresponding bi-conditional is valid.

As Mauro points out in his comment, it would be better to say φ and ψ are logically equivalent if they have the same truth value under all interpretations. Or, every model of each is a model of the other.
The proof of ⊨ φ ↔ ψ then follows via the deduction theorem.
From φ ⊨ ψ we get ⊨ φ → ψ and from ψ ⊨ φ we get ⊨ ψ → φ
Then by conjunction introduction we get ⊨ (φ → ψ) ∧ (ψ → φ) and so ⊨ φ ↔ ψ.
The converse also holds by application of modus ponens. Hence two propositions φ and ψ are logically equivalent if and only if their material equivalence is a valid sentence (or a tautology in the broad sense of that term).
It is important not to confuse material equivalence with logical equivalence, though unfortunately this is quite common. Material equivalence, or the material biconditional, is a truth-functional connective within the object language. Logical equivalence is a meta-level predicate on formulas that expresses that each has the other as its logical consequence. Logical equivalence entails material equivalence but is much stronger.
